# FLASK BuildError Python

Tags: python, flask

I cannot find what is wrong with my Flask app. I keep getting werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build URL for endpoint 'mark_report'.

Here is /index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>   <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/scripts.js') }}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">   </head>   <body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}   </body> </html>
```

Here is our main page

```
{% extends "index.html" %} {% block content %} <div class="container"> <div class="spacer">

  </div>   <div class="row header-row">
    <h1>EMS Suite</h1>   </div>   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item li-custom"><h3><a href="{{ url_for('mark_report') }}" style="color:#000000;">Mark Report</a></h3></li> </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      {% block page_content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>   </div>   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    </div> </nav> </div> {% endblock %}
```

Here is the route, there is an HTML page named mark_report.html in our template folders.

```
@app.route('/mark_report')
def mark_report():
   return render_template('mark_report.html')
```

Comment: try `{{ url_for('app.mark_report') }}`

Comment: @Craicerjack No luck man still, werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'app.mark_report'.

Comment: I tried your code and everything is working for me. I was able to redirect to url. Please check the configurations, directory and recommended to clear the cache and check.

Comment: Can you include how you create `app` and your project structure?

Comment: Also, please provide full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I made the mistake of having the below `if` statement above my routes.... Thank you everyone

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```